# Homogeneous differential equation $F(x, y, y',y'')$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying an example of a different equation's solution in my maths textbook. The equation is:
$$ xy'(yy'' - (y')^2) - y(y')^2 - x^4y^3 = 0$$
The author concludes that it is a homogeneous differential equation:
$$ F(x, ty, ty', ty'') = t^3[xy'(yy'' - (y')^2) - y(y')^2 - x^4y^3] = t^3F(x,y,y',y'') $$

But I can't understand why he left x without the factor. I thought the right way is to use F(tx, ty, ty', ty'') and in this case the equation isn't homogeneous.

Comment: I don't know how homogeneous differntial equations are meant to work (never come across them), but is it posible that y is a function of x? i.e. $y=y(x)$

Comment: @flipback : what do you mean  << he left x without the factor >> ? Which factor exactly are you thinking of ?. The author remplaces $y$ by $ty$. He never claims to remplace $x$ by $tx$. An Homogeneous ODE is an ODE so that both $y(x)$ and $c\:y(x)$ are solutions any $c$, with unchanged $x$ not with $c\:x$.

Comment: @JJacquelin According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation) definition a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ is homogeneous if $ f(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda f(x,y)$. But in my opinion it doesn't agree the author's solution. Of cause I understand that the solution is right. My question is why he left x when in the other part of the book I see $ f(\lambda x, \lambda y) $. What is the difference between these two cases?

Comment: There are several different definitions of ''homogeneous'' depending on the context. For example, see :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html  . Citation : <<  i.e., if all the terms are proportional to a derivative of y (or y itself) and there is no term that contains a function of x alone>>.

Comment: @ flipback : you refer to the part of a Wikipedia paper concerning homogeneous FUNCTION. In the same paper, the definition of homogeneous ODE is given, which is not to the same.

Comment: @JJacquelin I see! Could you write your comment as an answer? So that I can close the question.

Comment: @flipback : The comment is now written at the begining of my first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different definitions of ''homogeneous'' depending on the context. For example, see :  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html. Citation : << i.e., if all the terms are proportional to a derivative of y (or y itself) and there is no term that contains a function of x alone>>.

Also, in :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation  , a part of the Wikipedia paper concerns homogeneous FUNCTION. In the same paper, the definition of homogeneous ODE is given, which is not to the same.

Now, coming back to the ODE :

$$ xy'(yy'' - (y')^2) - y(y')^2 - x^4y^3 = 0 \quad\quad (1)$$
with $c\neq 0$ , remplacing $y$ by $cy$ leads to :
$$ c^3\left(xy'(yy'' - (y')^2) - y(y')^2 - x^4y^3 \right) = c^3(0)=0$$
Hense, if $y(x)$ is solution of $(1)$ then $cy(x)$ is also solution of $(1)$. This is the condition to be an homoneneous equation. So, $(1)$ is an homogeneous ODE.

Note : In the symbolic notation $F(x,y,y',y'')=0$, remplacing $y$ by $cy$ leads to $F(x,cy,cy',cy'')=0$ because $y'$ is remplaced by $(cy)'=cy'$ and $y''$ is rempaced by $(cy)''=cy''$. The variable $x$ remains unchanged. It should be a mistake to think that $F(x,y,y',y'')=0$ be remplaced by $F(cx,cy,cy',cy'')=0$.

To solve the ODE, change of function : $y(x)=e^{z(x)} \quad\rightarrow\quad y'=y\:z'\quad\rightarrow\quad y''=y(z'^2+z'')$

bringing back into $(1)$ and after simplification :
$$xz'z''-z'^2=x^4$$
$u=z'^2\quad\rightarrow\quad u'=2z'z''$
$$\frac{x}{2}u'-u=x^4$$
The solution of this linear ODE is :
$$u=x^4+c_1x^2$$
Then
$$z'=x\sqrt{x^2+c_1}$$
$$z=\int x\sqrt{x^2+c_1}dx= \frac{1}{3}\left(x^2+c_1 \right)^{3/2}+c_2$$
$$y=C\:\exp\left(\frac{1}{3}\left(x^2+c_1 \right)^{3/2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Define $z = ty$ as the function : $x \mapsto t\cdot y(x)$ 
$$ z'(x) = t\cdot y'(x)$$
$$ z''(x) = t\cdot y''(x)$$
$$ \begin{align}F(x, z(x), z'(x) ,z''(x)) &= F(x, ty(x), ty'(x) ,ty''(x)) \\
&= t^3[xy'(yy'' - (y')^2) - y(y')^2 - x^4y^3] \\
 &= t^3 F(x, y(x), y'(x) ,y''(x))
\end{align}$$
So we can conclude that if $x \mapsto y(x)$ is a solution, $x \mapsto t\cdot y(x)$ is also one.

$$ F(tx, ty(x), ty'(x),ty''(x)) = F(x, ty(\frac{x}{t}), ty'(\frac{x}{t}),ty''(\frac{x}{t}))$$

If we define $z : x \mapsto t\cdot y(\frac{x}{t})$ , then 
$$ z'(x) = y'(\frac{x}{t})$$
$$ z''(x) = \frac{1}{t}\cdot y''(\frac{x}{t})$$
That does not help.